# By using alternative repository for Maven I am not able to download some dependencies in java project?

Tags: java, maven, proxy

I am working behind a proxy and I am facing SSL issues. Therefore, I can't use HTTPS propertly, so in Eclipse in the settings.xml file of maven I set the repository to "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2", i.e. HTTP, as follows:

```
<settings>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>securecentral</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>securecentral</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</settings>
```

It worked for some dependencies but when I added one dependency to the pom.xml specifically this one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys.imageio</groupId>
    <artifactId>imageio-tiff</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Eclipse couldn't download it (I don't know if this issue is from the proxy, from the repository itself, or some other issue)

**My question:**
Does setting the repository to "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2" limit the number of plugins, libraries, or anything I can download using the normal repository "https://mvnrepository.com/", or it is exactly the same without any limitation or difference except that the first one is through HTTP not HTTPS ?

Comment: What error are you getting while trying to download via `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2`? Since the artifact is visibly there  - http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/imageio-tiff/3.3.2/

Comment: @nullpointer It is a transfer failed problem. But returning to my question: is http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 exactly the same as https://mvnrepository.com/ regarding the plugins, libraries, ..... or the second one is the standard and the bigger repository?

Comment: I hope you understand that both of these are repositories which includes artifacts uploaded via distributionManagement by developers. They are not same in terms of the endpoint you would reach and the first one is the preferred maven central - *http://repo1.maven.org/maven2* which can be looked in at **https://search.maven.org/**

Comment: To say it clear. https://mvnrepository.com is not a maven repository which can be used by Maven itself and it is not related to Maven Central...

Comment: @khmarbaise, nullpointer: 
In this case, what is the default repository that maven uses, Is it https://repo1.maven.org/maven2. 
And if "mvnrepository.com" is not a repository, so what is it (you mean it is only a web interface to search for artifacts in the repository http://repo1.maven.org/maven2.)?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you understand that both of these are repositories which include artifacts uploaded via `distributionManagement` by developers.

They are not same in terms of the endpoint you would reach.

The preferred would be the one for maven central - *http://repo1.maven.org/maven2* which can be looked in at **https://search.maven.org/**

There is a useful link for consumers to start using it. - [central.sonatype.org/pages/consumers](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/consumers.html) and the code shared seems to be following that very likely ([Consumer - Apache Maven](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/consumers.html#apache-maven))

Comment: Thanks for replying, in the provided link I didn't understand what is Sonatype essentially and what is the relation between it and Apache maven? Also you said "endpoint", do you mean the repository itself right?